# X to Wayland. What about Atoms?

Tags: linux, x11, wayland

I tried to port my little X software to Wayland. But Wayland is (in my opinion) very bad documented. 
Thats the reason for my question. How are the Atom properties handled in Wayland? (Not XWayland)

Comment: The request for a general checklist (vs the specific and answerable question about an equivalent to atoms) makes this arguably too broad to be a good StackOverflow question -- I'd suggest editing that out.

Comment: ...that said, why do you expect Wayland to *have* an equivalent to atoms at all? X11 atoms exist largely to make network transparency efficient; Wayland doesn't try to be network-transparent.

Comment: But how i communicate as a client to the compositor / window manager? With Atoms there is a "standard" way to do this. I dont want to change my code for every window manager. All window mangers use the same Atoms (freedesktop) and that is what iam aiming for with wayland.

Comment: *But how i communicate as a client to the compositor / window manager?* -- ...as the API documents, of course. Could you edit your question to be more specific about what you want to do (what kinds of window-management-related properties you intend to set, for instance) vs how you expect to do it?

Comment: In the documentation is nothing described. They discuss even if clients should draw for example window decorations by there own. But what if i want that this is compositor sided? How i can tell the compositor that i want to hide my decorations? Are there standard messages or whatever? I found nothing.

Comment: If that's your real question, *edit your question to actually ask that*.

Comment: That was only a example. Its about the whole concept of Atoms. How can i solve these basic things (that are solved by XAtoms in x11) with wayland?

Comment: *There is no concept of Atoms in Wayland.* Whether a specific mechanism for which you might be accustomed to using atoms in X11 has a Wayland interface offering similar functionality would be topical for a question about *that specific mechanism*. Assuming identical separation-of-concern design decisions is an assumption utterly without foundation, and frankly shows a lack of imagination: Just because X11 decided to do things in a given way doesn't mean everyone will make that same decision.